# ¿Como mostrar un unico valor de la db de Firebase, en Jsx de React?

Tags: javascript, base-de-datos, reactjs, firebase, read

En el código a continuación, estoy haciendo una tarea simple de extraer el valor de  "CÓDIGO" que se encuentra en mi db de firebase e imprimirlo en la pagina. Hasta el momento he logrado que obtenga los datos y los muestre en la consola, pero no logro que lo muestre en el jsx. Vengo de trabajar en kotlin y php, pero estoy empezando a usar Reactjs para hacer aplicaciones web. Aun no le agarro a la logica, espero puedan ayudarme con este ejercicio.

```js
import React, {
  useState,
  Fragment
} from "react";
import 'firebase/auth';
import {
  useFirebaseApp,
  useUser,
} from 'reactfire';
import 'firebase/database';

export default () => {

  //aqui llamas a firebase
  const firebase = useFirebaseApp();


  //objeto de formulas

  const [materia, setMateria] = useState(0);


  const database = firebase.database();

  database.ref(`/formulas`).on('value', (snapshot) => {

    const setMateria = snapshot.val().CODIGO
    console.log(setMateria);

    return;
  })




  return ( <
    Fragment >
    <
    div className = "container" >
    MOSTRAR MATERIA CODIGO: {
      materia
    }

    <
    /div> < /
    Fragment >
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la variable `materia` que quieres mostrar no tiene un valor. Tienes que asignarle el codigo que estas obteniendo de la base de datos.

```
 const [materia, setMateria] = useState(0);
database.ref(`/formulas`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
    const codigo = snapshot.val().CODIGO;
    setMateria(codigo); // aqui estas "seteando" el codigo al state que esta definido antes.

    return;
  })




  return (
<Fragment >
    <div className = "container" >
        MOSTRAR MATERIA CODIGO: {materia}
    </div>
</ Fragment >
  )
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Igual debo mencionar que debía también cambiar en 
"database.ref(`/formulas`).on('value',(snapshot)=>"

por 
"database.ref(`/formulas`).once('value',(snapshot)=>"

Remplace el "on" por "once" Para que no se generara un error por actualizar ese valor constantemente